# How could I join the sublist inside a list?

Tags: python, list

How could I join the sublist inside a list?
I had done this,

```
from collections import deque
new_list = []

def sort_sequence(lst):
    lst = "".join([str(i) for i in lst])
    lst = [list(i + "0") for i in lst.split("0") if i]
    lst = [[int(j) for j in i] for i in lst] 
    lst = [sorted(k) for k in lst]

    for i  in range(len(lst)):
        item = deque(lst[i])
        item.rotate(-1)
        new_list.append(list(item))
    print(new_list)
        
    
sort_sequence([1,3,2,0,5,4,6,0,2,3,4,0])
```

For example:

I want this list *[[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0], [2, 3, 4, 0]]* as *[1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0]*

Please help me with this.

Comment: You mean flatten it?

Comment: Just for fun. If there are only single digits the whole function body could be: `return list(map(int, '0'.join(''.join(sorted(s)) for s in ''.join(map(str, seq)).split('0'))))`

Answer (score 0):

No need to import any module. Recursion will do it.

```
new_list = []

def sort_sequence(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            sort_sequence(i) 
        else:
            new_list.append(i)
    print(new_list)   
    
sort_sequence([1,3,2,0,5,4,6,0,2,3,4,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

```
In [1]: from itertools import chain

In [2]: a = [[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0], [2, 3, 4, 0]]

In [3]: b = list(chain.from_iterable(a))

In [4]: b
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending to the list, you can add to it and get your desired result. Use this code:

```
from collections import deque


def sort_sequence(lst):
    lst = "".join([str(i) for i in lst])
    lst = [list(i + "0") for i in lst.split("0") if i]
    lst = [[int(j) for j in i] for i in lst] 
    lst = [sorted(k) for k in lst]
    new_list = []
    for i  in range(len(lst)):
        item = deque(lst[i])
        item.rotate(-1)
        new_list = new_list + list(item)
    print(new_list)
        
    
sort_sequence([1,3,2,0,5,4,6,0,2,3,4,0])
```